# Can tensors be concatenated without losing reference in torch (lua)?

Tags: lua, torch

```
th> x = torch.rand(2)
                                                                  [0.4943s] 
th> y = torch.rand(2)
                                                                  [0.0001s] 
th> x
 0.6115
 0.4986
[torch.DoubleTensor of size 2]
                                                                  [0.0002s] 
th> z = torch.cat(x,y)
                                                                  [0.0003s] 
th> z
 0.6115
 0.4986
 0.5171
 0.1785
[torch.DoubleTensor of size 4]

                                                                  [0.0001s] 
th> z[1] = 3
                                                                  [0.0001s] 
th> z[1]
 3  
                                                                  [0.0001s] 
th> x[1]
 0.61146148154512
```

Modifying z **does not** modify x. Is there any way of concatenating x and y such that modifying z does modify x?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this kind of behaviour, but the other way around. You should start with a bigger tensor, your main "storage", and then you can create subtensors, which will share internal state.

See in particular `:sub` method from torch (following code sample taken from [Torch doc](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/tensor.md))

```
x = torch.Tensor(5, 6):zero()
> x
 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0
[torch.DoubleTensor of dimension 5x6]

y = x:sub(2,4):fill(1) -- y is sub-tensor of x:
> y                    -- dimension 1 starts at index 2, ends at index 4
 1  1  1  1  1  1
 1  1  1  1  1  1
 1  1  1  1  1  1
[torch.DoubleTensor of dimension 3x6]

> x                    -- x has been modified!
 0  0  0  0  0  0
 1  1  1  1  1  1
 1  1  1  1  1  1
 1  1  1  1  1  1
 0  0  0  0  0  0
[torch.DoubleTensor of dimension 5x6]
```

As you can see you have `y` variable which is actually a part of `x`, and changing its values - change x's too. This is very generic way thus you can share multiple parts of tensor.

Thus in your case it would be something like

```
z = torch.Tensor(4):zero()
x = z:sub(1, 2)
y = z:sub(3, 4)
x[1] = 2
y[2] = 8
print(z)
```

prints

```
 2
 0
 0
 8
[torch.DoubleTensor of size 4]
```

as desired.

Comment: Thanks for that! Unfortunately in my case, I cannot create the larger "main" storage. The two tensors in question are parameters of two neural network models, and hence their storage is created by the model. I do however get a 'handle' on the storage. The exact method in question is the [getParameters method](https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/master/Module.lua)
What I wanted to do was to 'combine' the parameters of the models so that I could use a unified optimization method from the [optim package](https://github.com/torch/optim/blob/master/adam.lua).

Comment: then you should use the same package (nn) to build an actual model out of your components. There are plenty of container based modules which allow you to compose multiple networks into one - then calling getParams on container realocates everything to a single tensor